# Does the Flag Posts section of the Privileges description need to be updated

Tags: discussion, feature-request, privileges-page

In the [Flag Posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts) section of the Privileges explanation, it currently says that there are 3 Flag Types, as follows:

> 1. Offensive, Abusive, or Hate Speech
> 2. Spam (i.e. undiscriminated bulk advertisement)
> 3. Requires moderator attention

At some point, the flagging options were changed to include another Flag Type as follows:

> It doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate

This option is shown in the screenshot on the "Flag Posts" section, and has been modified slightly in the window that comes up when you click to flag a question.

[image]

If you select this option, there are a number of different options you can choose for why the question does not belong.  Based on this SO blog post discussing [Improved Flagging](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/), it appears that this option throws a Moderator Attention flag, like the first option, but with a specific set of reasons why.

Each of the first 3 flag types have additional explanation for what happens when that flag is chosen.  Should some description of this new option be added, or does it fall under the guise of requiring moderator attention?

Comment: Because this question addresses a generic feature of *all* SE sites, I am migrating it to Meta SO for attention there.

Comment: @whuber, Thanks for migrating.  I didn't think about the fact that GISse is but a tree in the forest of SE, and that those are actually global descriptions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have updated that wiki page, which now lists the following flags:

1. Requires ♦ moderator attention
2. Off-topic, not a real question, too localized, not constructive, duplicate question
3. Spam (i.e. [undiscriminated bulk advertisement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/how-does-the-spam-flag-work))
4. Offensive, abusive, or hate speech

The change in the wiki page still needs to be pushed to the other Stack Exchange site; the wiki page on this very site is the one used as master (as far as I recall).

Comment: That settles that I guess!  I know it was a rather minor item, but I thought it might be confusing for a new user trying to familiarize themselves with the site.  Thanks!